how to listen for onDone events in react xstate v5
In xstate v4 it used to be possible to listen for a service's onDone event by doing the following:
const [state, send, service] = useMachine(fsm)


useEffect(() => {
  const listener = () => {
    props.submit(state.context) // or similar
  };

  service.onDone(listener);

  return () => { service.off(listener) }
}, [service, props.submit]);

However in xstate v5, useMachine returns an ActorRef rather than a Service, and ActorRef does not have an onDone function.
Is there any way to listen for final states using idiomatic React, or do we need to pass the action to the machine as described here?

Yes, use an observer:
const [state, send, actor] = useMachine(fsm);

useEffect(() => {
  const sub = actor.subscribe({
    complete: () => {/* ... */}
  });
  return sub.unsubscribe;
}, [actor]);

